# How to filter invalid incoming json data in Kafka KStream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a KStream which reads json messages from a kafka (2.3.0) topic. Because i can not guarantee, that all these message are valid json messages, the result are JsonParseExceptions, which let my program crash and it seems, that they are not manageable by Kafka.

I have created the following source code, which works fine for valid messages, which are then parsed as JsonNodes.

```java
    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    final Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom( new JsonSerializer(), new JsonDeserializer());
    final Consumed<String, JsonNode> consumed = Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde);
    final KStream<String, JsonNode> input = builder.stream("myTopic", consumed);
```

In my case there are a few XML messages in the topic and they are not parsable to JsonNode-Object. The following exceptions are thrown:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (byte[])"<StupidXML>"[truncated 289 bytes]; line: 1, column: 2]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (byte[])"<StupidXML>"[truncated 289 bytes]; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
```

Are there any possibilities to react of throwing Exceptions? Or is there some kind of configuration of "ignoring / logging" invalid messages? Or catching these exceptions?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG` property to chose deserialization exception handler.

By default it is `org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndFailExceptionHandler` according to java doc:

> Deserialization handler that logs a deserialization exception and then
>   signals the processing pipeline to stop processing more records and
>   fail.

You can change it to `org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler`:

> Deserialization handler that logs a deserialization exception and then
>   signals the processing pipeline to continue processing more records.

You can also create your custom deserialization exception handler, you only have to implement [DeserializationExceptionHandler](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/errors/DeserializationExceptionHandler.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, sometimes it is easier as expected.